# Alternative to 'dirty minded?'

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, adjectives

For example, an aunt saw you come out of a room with another guy. The first thing the comes to her mind is you are having sex with the guy. What words would you use to describe her?

Comment: Presumptive/Presumptuous?

Comment: Your question is off-topic unless you edit it according to our guidelines. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*.

Comment: Suspicious (or perhaps perceptive )

Comment: @Rathony: Minor point, but I'd word your warning as follows: "In order to be answered, questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how they will be used." No biggie. Don

Comment: @rhetorician Hello, Don. I just used one of the close reasons as is worded. You can check the original version by clicking on close > Off-Topic > *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: About single word requests*.

Comment: @ Rathony: No need to check; I believe you. Perhaps the person who wrote the criterion is the person who needs to revise it! Don

Answer (score 2):

A word I do not hear very often, but is relevant here, is *suspect*. Of your "aunt" you might ask yourself,

> I wonder why Aunt Tilly is so suspect of people.

The connotation of suspect (sŭs′pĕkt′) in that sense is that Aunt Tilly is particularly open to, or views people with, suspicion.

Answer (score 1):

Since we lack usage, a synonym of "dirty-minded" as mentioned in the title is **"Salacious:"**

> relating to sex in a way that is excessive or offensive
>
> -Merriam Webster